# Testing CSS fallback for linear-gradient with Rails Mailer Previews / Letter Openeer

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, email, html-email, actionmailer

I'm trying to get a fallback background-colour working for our Email template below:-

```
<a href="/" style="
   background-image: linear-gradient(134.72deg, #3023AE 0%, #C86DD7 100%)" 
   background-color: #7c47c2;
</a>
```

The above works in most browsers/clients, aside from MS Outlook on some Windows platforms - what happens is the background is just blank, with the color not being applied.

I've switched the order to the below now:-

```
<a href="/" style="
   background-color: #7c47c2;
   background-image: linear-gradient(134.72deg, #3023AE 0%, #C86DD7 100%)" 
</a>
```

This works on the clients that were broken before, but what happens here is the background-color now overrides the linear gradient which never displays.

When I inspect the emails, the background-image property isn't even present in the source of the email.

My question is - where does this property disappear to when I'm viewing it as a Rails Mailer Preview?

Comment: Have you tried putting the background-image linear gradient both before and after the background color?

Comment: You mean repeating the background-image property?  No but I'll try that.

Comment: Can you post more context, i.e. the final result (even if it includes dummy content), as it's really tough to see the code around the element that could be causing issues.
For one, the gradient on the a tag directly may not actually be the best idea and it would be helpful to see the wrapping structure to see if an alternative approach would work for the gradient + fall back.

Comment: Have you tried just `background`? Give it a try, `background: #7c47c2;background-color: #7c47c2; background-image: linear-gradient(134.72deg, #3023AE 0%, #C86DD7 100%);`

Answer (score -2):

This is because `linear-background` is not a property of `background-image`. It should be `background`, not `background-image`, and then it will work.

You should put the background-color first, because you want the gradient to override it (if supported). The email clients that don't support it will simply remove the gradient part.